# Cassandra create duplicate table with different primary key

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm new to Apache Cassandra and have the following issue:

I have a table with `PRIMARY KEY (userid, countrycode, carid)`. As described in many tutorials this table can be queried by using following filter criteria:

- userid = x
- userid = x and countrycode = y
- userid = x and countrycode = y and carid = z

This is fine for most cases, but now I need to query the table by filtering only on

- userid = x and carid = z

Here, the documentation sais that is the best solution to create another table with a modified primary key, in this case `PRIMARY KEY (userid, carid, countrycode)`.

The question here is, how to copy the data from the "original" table to the new one with different index?

- On small tables
- On huge tables

And another important question concerning the duplication of a huge table: What about the storage needed to save both tables instead of only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COPY command to export from one table and import into other table.

From your example - I created 2 tables. user_country and user_car with respective primary keys.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE user WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',  'datacenter1' : 2 } ;
CREATE TABLE user.user_country ( user_id text, country_code text, car_id text, PRIMARY KEY (user_id, country_code, car_id));
CREATE TABLE user.user_car ( user_id text, country_code text, car_id text, PRIMARY KEY (user_id, car_id, country_code));
```

Let's insert some dummy data into one table.

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO user.user_country (user_id, country_code, car_id) VALUES ('1', 'IN', 'CAR1');
cqlsh> INSERT INTO user.user_country (user_id, country_code, car_id) VALUES ('2', 'IN', 'CAR2');
cqlsh> INSERT INTO user.user_country (user_id, country_code, car_id) VALUES ('3', 'IN', 'CAR3');
cqlsh> select * from user.user_country ;

 user_id | country_code | car_id
---------+--------------+--------
       3 |           IN |   CAR3
       2 |           IN |   CAR2
       1 |           IN |   CAR1

(3 rows)
```

Now we will export the data into a CSV. **Observe the sequence of columns mentioned.**

```
cqlsh> COPY user.user_country (user_id,car_id, country_code) TO 'export.csv';
Using 1 child processes

Starting copy of user.user_country with columns [user_id, car_id, country_code].
Processed: 3 rows; Rate:       4 rows/s; Avg. rate:       4 rows/s
3 rows exported to 1 files in 0.824 seconds.
```

export.csv can now be directly inserted into other table.

```
cqlsh> COPY user.user_car(user_id,car_id, country_code) FROM 'export.csv';
Using 1 child processes

Starting copy of user.user_car with columns [user_id, car_id, country_code].
Processed: 3 rows; Rate:       6 rows/s; Avg. rate:       8 rows/s
3 rows imported from 1 files in 0.359 seconds (0 skipped).
cqlsh>
cqlsh>
cqlsh> select * from user.user_car ;

 user_id | car_id | country_code
---------+--------+--------------
       3 |   CAR3 |           IN
       2 |   CAR2 |           IN
       1 |   CAR1 |           IN

(3 rows)
cqlsh>
```

About your other question - yes the data will be duplicated, but that's how cassandra is used.

Comment: Awesome answer.  And you're absolutely correct...Cassandra is all about trading disk space for performance.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! But exporting to e.g. CSV is extremely cumbersome for huge tables, isn't it?

Comment: It could be time consuming for sure and may have CPU spike while export/import happening. You can always tune COPY command using batch size, timeouts etc. But given this is going to be one time task to match up 2 tables, it should be ok. After this, your application inserting data into existing table has to also insert the data into new table.

Comment: COPY will fail on the huge tables. It also won't handle metadata correctly